# Changing a query from subqueries to joins

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to optimize a query and I believe I can do it with joins as opposed to subqueries but I am not sure how to. Bellow is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   accounts 
WHERE  LOWER(firstname) = LOWER('Sam') 
       AND id IN (SELECT account_id 
                  FROM   addresses 
                  WHERE  LOWER(name) = LOWER('Street1')) 
       AND id IN (SELECT account_id 
                  FROM   alternate_ids 
                  WHERE  alternate_id_glbl = '5');
```

I have 3 tables: accounts, addresses, and alternate ID's. When I do a search I want to return the set of accounts that have a first name of Sam, an address of Street 1, and an alternate ID of 5.

There is an account_id column in the address and alternate ID tables that has the ID of the account it is associated with.

Do you have any ideas on how I could turn this into query that uses joins or possibly a more efficient query?

Oh and this is a postgres DB

Comment: Why would you like to use joins/make it more efficient?  Is it currently taking too long to execute?

Comment: Yes exactly, I have already done indexing, but performance was still sub par, with the joins though it appears to have cut the time in half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT acc.* 
FROM accounts acc 
JOIN addresses addr ON acc.id = addr.account_id
JOIN alternate_ids ids ON acc.id = ids.account_id
WHERE LOWER(acc.firstname) = LOWER('Sam') 
AND LOWER(addr.name) = LOWER('Street1') 
AND ids.alternate_id_glbl = '5';
```

However, it is not guaranteed that this version will work better, as the query optimizer usually automatically tunes the execution plan.

Comment: I am going to give this a quick run and I will let you know, looks great though!

Comment: Works well both you and Ochi Wansa presented the same solution and it cut my query time in about half which is great. I already asked him but what is the significance of the ON?

Comment: The `ON` clause specifies the `JOIN` condition, i.e. the condition that criteria that must be met to join rows of two different tables. Thus, additional criteria might be specified in the `ON` or in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the execution plan to see if it is already using a join? The query optimiser will do it if possible.

You might place indexes on the account table LOWER(firstname) and the addresses table LOWER(name).

Comment: Already did the indexing, its a very large dataset so even with indexing the performance is not up to snuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT acc.*
FROM accounts acc
JOIN addresses add
  ON acc.id = add.account_id
    AND LOWER(add.name) = LOWER('Street1')
JOIN alternate_ids alt
  ON acc.id = alt.account_id
    AND alt.alternate_id_glbl = '5'
WHERE LOWER(acc.firstname) = LOWER('Sam');
```